# Combine two vectors in R, convert to string

Tags: r

I have two numerical vectors in R

```
c(1,2,3,4,5)
c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
```

I would like to convert them to strings, combine them, and apply formatting, producing one vector:

```
c("1 (10.0%)", "2 (20.0%)", "3 (30.0%)", "4 (40.0%)", "5 (50.0%)")
```

It's more important for the solution to be simple and comprehensible than performant in my case.

Comment: Good point, that was a typo, they are in fact the same length.  Editing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5)

y <- paste0(y * 100, "%")
result <- paste0(x," (", y, ")")
```

Comment: Or all in one shot: `paste0(x, " (", y*100, "%)")`. If @juwiley wants to keep the decimal points, then try `paste0(x," (", sprintf("%.1f", y*100), ")")` as Ananda Mahto suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple implementation:

```
> num      <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> pct      <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
> 
> pctChar  <- paste0("(", pct*100, "%", ")")
> char.out <- paste(num, pctChar)
> char.out
[1] "1 (10%)" "2 (20%)" "3 (30%)" "4 (40%)" "5 (50%)"
```

Note that `paste0()` by default does not put spaces between the components, and that `paste()` does.

Comment: (I dropped the second `0.3`, which I interpreted as a typo.)

Comment: might i suggest dropping the "[.0]%"? what if it's .125 for 12.5%?

Comment: I suppose I was being silly, @imsoconfused. I'll change it ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the note on paste0 vs paste